# Passing column name as argument in function within pipes

Tags: function, dplyr, tidyverse

I'm trying to write a function by passing a variable name as an argument. This is then used in a downstream pipe to mutate a variable.

Using a more classic but perhaps a little bit clunky approach I am able to do this:

```
var = "Sepal.Width"

scale_fun1 = function(dat,var) {
  
  dat[,"new_var"] = dat[,var]*100
  
  return(dat)
  
}

scale_fun1(iris,var)
```

I thought this would be straightforward using a pipe but it's proving more difficult then I thought as when the function passes the pipe var it doesn't parse as it should which results in a non-numeric argument to binary operator error. How can this be fixed please?

```
var = "Sepal.Width"

scale_fun2 = function(dat,var) {
  
  iris %>% dplyr::mutate(new_variable = var * 100)
  
}

scale_fun2(iris,var)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make use of non standard evaluation which is worth a quick read about. In this case you most likely need to `!!` infront of `var` in the mutate line.

Here's the line:

```
mutate(new_variable = !!sym(var) * 100)
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the input. I'll read into non-standard evaluation. I tried:
  `iris %>% dplyr::mutate(new_variable = !!var * 100)`  but it didn't work.

Comment: apologies, try my edit

Comment: Thank you. That works. I really need to know this stuff....!